# Where do I look for a new-to-the-network technical-overview introduction to what a script/app/etc. basically is, incl. differences between them?

Tags: support, documentation, meta, dev-tip

Where do I look for a new-to-the-network technical-overview introduction to what a script/app/etc. basically is, including differences between them?

Basically, I'm looking for onboarding documentation pointers, or search terms to find that sort of info regarding all the (not legacy-deprecated-unavailable-etc.) sorts of functions discussed on StackApps, scripts, apps, or whatever. Terminology definitions and tutorials or well-documented examples... whatever I can read. Public stacks are my focus for now.

Also if other stacks, or unofficial / off-network resources deal with similar topics, pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a lot in the questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), and the API has a comprehensive [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/) with the option to test your calls online.

The best guide here (that I know of) to what a script is (on Stack Apps), is the [[script] tag wiki](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info). They are written in JavaScript so you can read their source code for inspiration.

Other usages of the API fall under [app](/questions/tagged/app), which is pretty broad indeed. It might be a mobile app, desktop app or a console program. If you're building a component, rather than an end product, you can use the [library](/questions/tagged/library) tag.